# Debugging a linux kernel module using serial port

Tags: linux, module, gdb, kernel, kgdb

I'm trying to setup simple kernel debugging, I have a 3.2.6 kernel on VM (ESXi), which I declared a serial port (I manage to connect to the serial )

### Debugger:

[image: Debugger Screenie]

### Debuggee:

[image: Debugee Screenie]

I followed [this tutorial on how to setup gdb](http://thefmaj7.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/using-built-in-kgdb-with-kernel-2-6-32-under-vmware-vms/), and I seem to be getting replies (the serial port seems to be fine) when I start debugging, however gdb is getting junk and doesn't manage to debug anything,

I encountered [a thread on lkml from 2k10](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.debugging/1956) which stated a similar problem on 2.6.35 kernel, however a patch has been committed (I guess went into mainstream) and I'm trying to debug 3.2.6

This is what I'm getting from gdb :
[image: GDB Output]

and here's a the output from the vm: 
[image: VM Output]

Can anyone hint me on how to solve it ?

<sub>(If any mod could edit my message and transform all images to real images and links to real links that would be awesome too, the system didn't allow that and I have to edit my post 4-5 times before posting :/ )</sub>

Comment: "Getting junk" from serial port usually refers to baud rate errors. Check baud rate options on both ends (they must be the same).

Comment: @Huhu did you solve your problem? I'm sorry it's taken such a long time for someone to come by, I formatted your question. Please tell me if your issue isn't solved and we'll try and do something about it?